# Project build missing Simperium app property?

Tags: android, simperium

I am following the steps described here to use the Simperium :

https://simperium.com/tutorials/simpletodo-android/

After importing Code from GitHub. 
message Gradle sync is showing : Project build missing Simperium app property.

and on opening the file in build.gradle studio is showing error in  following line:

```
 throw new ProjectConfigurationException("Project build missing ${property} property", null)
```

Is there any solution or suggestion to run this sample??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed this step:

> Next, navigate to the /Simpletodo folder and edit the gradle.properties-example file. You'll notice the placeholders for your App Id and API Key there. Replace them with your values acquired in Step 1, and then save and rename the file to gradle.properties

Once the gradle.properties file is set up, the app should build.